# How to get the appbarlayout to scroll slower than its sibling nested scroll view in Coordinator layout system?

Tags: android, android-coordinatorlayout

I have an AppBarLayout with height around 200dp, and I have a nested scroll view sibling to the appbarlayout all wrapped inside a coordinatorlayout, how do I get the appbarlayout to scroll slower than nested scroll view, ideally using `CoordinatorLayout.Behavior`  Like so:-

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"` to a layout inside CollapsingToolbarLayout. With this you will get parallax effect on your scroll.

Comment: nah the appbarlayout scrolls up first before the nested scroll view starts scrolling

Comment: Sorry, my bad.
I know for sure that you can do that using
com.github.ksoichiro.android.observablescrollview.ObservableScrollView but have no idea how to do that using CollapsingToolbarLayout.